# Array obtained from $.load as select options Laravel Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I am currently working on a dynamically produced modal to assign users of my application to a mentor. But, these mentors belong to a specific team so only the mentors from the user's team should be a option to assign.

I have gotten to this point, when the users are selected and the option is enabled to assign a new mentor a modal is popped-up. This modal shows the users (their name etc) and with this code:

```
$("#selected-coach").load('{{ route('admin.api.bulk_get_coaches') }}?' + $.param({team: team_selected}));
```

The coaches are shown in the modal in such a way:

```
{"1":"Madyson","2":"Lorenzo","3":"Hector"}
```

This array is syntax wise ready to be put into my `{!! Form:select('mentor', *array of coaches*, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`. This laravel form generated a select/option field in my modal. But I can not figure out how I am suppose to the the array in the select/option field?

Comment: You can use array_map function to build an array with id and respective value and then pass it on blade

Comment: I don't think you should use `$.load`. That is used to fetch some HTML and inject it into your document. Your URL appears to be returning JSON

Comment: @Phil would be better to use `$.getJSON` then?

Comment: I'd say so. You won't be able to use it in Laravel's `Form:select` helper as that is server-side. Does the `<select>` element exist when your JavaScript runs? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Thank you very much @Phil! I adjust the code to get the JSON with `$.getJSON`, `$(#mentor).empty();` and loop through the JSON with `mentor.append("<option value='"+ index +"'>" + element + "</option>");`!

Comment: @AnnaJeanine feel free to answer your own question. That's a solid solution that might help others

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Phil!

```
$.getJSON('{{ route('admin.api.bulk_get_coaches') }}?' + $.param({team: team_selected}), function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(index, element) {
         $('#coach').append("<option value='"+ index +"'>" + element + "</option>");
     });
});
```

Comment: I'd probably go with `$('<option>').val(index).text(element).appendTo('#coach')` in case the `index` or `element` variables aren't safe for HTML

Comment: Works great too :-)!